# Scrolling to a particular item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component, I'm displaying a list of items -- each in its own DIV element with a unique id i.e. `<div id="abc-123">`.

I'm also using `react-perfect-scrollbar` to make the whole thing nicer looking.

I keep a variable in my reducer named `activeElementId` and when the value of `activeElementId` changes, I want to automatically scroll to that item on the screen.

Setting the `activeElementId` is the easy part but I'm not sure how to scroll to that element and would appreciate some pointers.

This is the parent component that contains the `ListComponent`.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   render() {

      return(

         <div>
             {this.props.items.length > 0 
                ? 
                <PerfectScrollBar>
                  <ListComponent items={this.props.items} />
                </PerfectScrollBar>
                : null}
         </div>
      );

   }
}
```

My `ListComponent` is a presentational component:

```
const ListComponent = ({ items }) => {

   return(
       <ul className="pretty-list">
           {items.map(item => <ItemComponents item={item} />)}
       </ul>
   );
}

export default ListComponent;
```

And the `ItemComponent` is a presentational component as well:

```
const ItemComponent = ({ Item }) => {

   return(
       <li>
           <div id={item.id}>
              {item.someProperty}
           </div>
       </li>
   );
}

export default ItemComponent;
```

I really like the idea of keeping `ListComponent` and `ItemComponent` separate and as presentational components as that helps keep the code simpler and easier to manage. Not sure if that would make it difficult to implement the auto scroll logic though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you use has a method called [`setScrollTop`](https://github.com/goldenyz/react-perfect-scrollbar#methods). You can use it with [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). To use `getBoundingClientRect` you need to have the dom-element. You didn't give any code about how you are setting or getting the active element but I'll try to give you an example. Maybe it will help you to implement on your code.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  _onListItemChange = (itemsPosition) => {
    this.scrollbar.setScrollTop(itemsPosition.top);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.length > 0 ? 
          <PerfectScrollBar ref={(scrollbar) => { this.scrollbar = scrollbar; }}>
            <ListComponent
              items={this.props.items}
              onListItemChange={this._onListItemChange} />
          </PerfectScrollBar>
         : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

---

```
const ListComponent = ({ items, onListItemChange }) => {

   return(
       <ul className="pretty-list">
           {items.map(item => (
               <ItemComponents
                 item={item}
                 onListItemClick={onListItemChange} />
            ))}
       </ul>
   );
}

export default ListComponent;
```

---

```
import { render, findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

class ListItem extends React.Component {

  _onClick = () => {
    let domElement = findDOMNode(this.item);
    this.props.onListItemClick(domElement.getBoundingClientRect());
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return(
      <li>
        <div id={item.id} ref={(item) => { this.item = item; }} onClick={this._onClick}>
          {item.someProperty}
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. A quick follow up: I'd like to add animation to the scroll without using jQuery. I checked the documentation of `setScrollTop` but I see no reference to animations. Could you point me in the right direction on this? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sam glad that it worked but I'm afraid I don't have any experience/knowledge on that topic. Try doing a little bit more research and if nothing comes up opening up a new question would be a good idea.

Comment: i tried to implement your solution but i get an error:   Cannot read property 'setScrollTop' of undefined. when i use console.log on the itemsPosition.top i get the value 133. so there is a value here.

Comment: @TheWeeezel be sure that you are binding functions correctly and not loosing context of `this`. Also be sure that you are getting the `ref` right.

Comment: okay. im using exactly the same ref you have and my functions looks pretty much the same: `onItemFindDom = (itemsPosition) => {
    console.log(itemsPosition.left);
    this.scrollbar.setScrollTop(itemsPosition.top);
  }`

Comment: @TheWeeezel I can't be helpful without any [mcve]. If you think you tried everything you can always create a new question. Give enough details so people can debug your problem. I'm sorry if I can't be helpful.

Comment: @bennygenel is there a way to do this without any library?